# Can't seem to be able to move my objects using java

Tags: java

I seem to be unable to move any objects I bring into my class, my other classes seem to be functional when I set bounds, but not this one.

I'm wondering why it isn't working and functionally like my other classes.

Some of the bounds are extreme as that's me making sure I can notice if any of the objects are moving; which they are not.

```
package student.information.in.java;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class CreatedBy extends JFrame {

    JButton btnJoelHogg, btnAndrewCameron, btnConorElliman, btnTiarnanByrne, btnproject;
    JLabel lblJoel, lblAndrew, lblConor, lblTiarnan, lbl_title, lbl_Info;

    public CreatedBy() {

        super("Project team and information");
        setLayout(null);

        lbl_title = new JLabel("Information about the system & its creators", JLabel.CENTER);
        add(lbl_title);
        lbl_title.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
        lbl_title.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        lbl_title.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        lblJoel = new JLabel("Joel Hogg");
        add(lblJoel);
        lblJoel.setBounds(30, 140, 200, 30);
        lblJoel.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblJoel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        btnJoelHogg = new JButton("About Joel");
        btnJoelHogg.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        btnJoelHogg.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnJoelHogg.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        lblAndrew = new JLabel("Andrew Cameron");
        add(lblAndrew);
        lblAndrew.setBounds(80, 50, 400, 30);
        lblAndrew.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblAndrew.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        btnAndrewCameron = new JButton("About Andrew");
        btnAndrewCameron.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        btnAndrewCameron.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnAndrewCameron.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        lblJoel = new JLabel("Conor Elliman");
        add(lblJoel);
        lblJoel.setBounds(20, 540, 170, 380);
        lblJoel.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblJoel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        btnConorElliman = new JButton("About Conor");
        btnConorElliman.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        btnConorElliman.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnConorElliman.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        lblTiarnan = new JLabel("Tiarnán");
        add(lblTiarnan);
        lblTiarnan.setBounds(202, 506, 170, 30);
        lblTiarnan.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblTiarnan.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        btnTiarnanByrne = new JButton("About Tiarnán");
        btnTiarnanByrne.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        btnTiarnanByrne.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnTiarnanByrne.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        Container c = getContentPane();

        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);

        c.setLayout(fl);

        c.add(btnJoelHogg);
        c.add(btnAndrewCameron);
        c.add(btnConorElliman);
        c.add(btnTiarnanByrne);

        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

        btnJoelHogg.addActionListener(handler);
        btnAndrewCameron.addActionListener(handler);
        btnConorElliman.addActionListener(handler);
        btnTiarnanByrne.addActionListener(handler);
        setSize(600, 400);

        show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Make frame
        CreatedBy f = new CreatedBy();

        f.addWindowListener(
                new WindowAdapter() {

                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

                        System.out.println("Exit via windowClosing.");

                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                }
        );

    } // end of main

    // inner class for button event handling
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == btnJoelHogg) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Joel Hogg button pressed");
            }

            if (e.getSource() == btnAndrewCameron) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Andrew Cameron button pressed");
            }

            if (e.getSource() == btnTiarnanByrne) {
                System.out.println("Tiarnan Byrne button pressed");
            }
            if (e.getSource() == btnConorElliman) {
                System.out.println("Conor Elliman button pressed");
            }

        }

    } // end of inner class

} // end of outer class
```

Comment: What if you where to try `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {CreatedBy f = new CreatedBy();

        f.addWindowListener(
                new WindowAdapter() {

                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

                        System.out.println("Exit via windowClosing.");

                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                }
        )});`. This should ensure that everything goes through the Event Dispatching Thread.

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.